# C# Write text to another program, from the background

Tags: c#, background

Hello I am doing a program that will notice when a specific key is pressed and write an specific letter where the person is writing. I had thought of doing it in a Console app or should i do it in an Windows Forms? I don't either now how to get it to work in the background or how to to write it out where the user do write?

the code i have done until now looks like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
            cki = Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine(cki.Key.ToString());

            if (cki.Key.ToString() == "F" && (cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0)
            {
                //typ something where the person is writing
            }
        }
    }
```

thanks for all help

Comment: `SendKeys` used to be my old friend ...

Comment: but i can't get it to work...

Comment: the features of `SendKeys` got disabled by some windows-fix ... microsoft released a hotfix way back to windows xp sp1 - since then, `SendKeys` aren't working anymore under special circumstances ...

Comment: ok but do you know some other way of doing it?

Comment: flaimme: an ultimate-on-all-versions-of-windows-working solution? nope ... sry!

Comment: but on a windows 7 solution??

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I've never heard of this problem, could you show a link?

Comment: @annonymously we (@ my work) created a program, which used `SendKeys` (some very special programm ... hehe). the machine was running xp and the program got broken at some point by some hotfix. when we've reverted the machine back to pre sp1, everything worked normal - our hw-support could identify the special fix, but i was never interested in that. the main thing for me was, that it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` then you can do this:

```
//outside namespace:
using TSendKeys = System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys;

//To type a key:
TSendKeys.Send("Put whatever you want here");
```

Comment: As I said in my post, you need to add a reference to the `System.Windows.Forms` dll. You right click the References item under your project, and then click `Add Reference`

Comment: tanks it took me some minutes to realise that :P